# WPF 4 FixedDocument multiple pages

Tags: wpf, flowdocument, fixeddocument

What is the best way to print a complex layout spanning multiple pages in WPF? (for example an invoice layout spanning multiple pages because of many invoice items)

I'm guessing one of these methods would do:

- Dynamically inserting pages in a FixedDocument? how?
- Convert a FlowDocument to a FixedDocment. How? The solutions found do not seem to work in WPF 4 (fox example http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fyuan/archive/2007/03/10/convert-xaml-flow-document-to-xps-with-style-multiple-page-page-size-header-margin.aspx)

Comment: I might be bit late to answer [but this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43468782/2639185) answer can help.

Answer (score 0):

I typically use dynamic insertion of Pages into the FixedDocument control. I created a empty view and then dynamically load in UserControls that represent each pages "body" with their respective binding(s). The downside is you have to create your own poormans virtualization for dataset reprots (ie show 12 rows per page with a MOD 12 calculation etc) type thing.

Reports are low priority on the WPF teams Radar so this really hasn't got a lot of knowledge base around it at present and the future isn't so bright either.

Comment: I am in a similar position. I can understand MS in general might aim for other reporting technologies but in instances like this @scottbarnes, I think it's more of a "document" semantic which then means using reporting technology to do this is a workaround.

I know this is old, but I still haven't found proper information on this. =) Wonder if anyone has an answer?